# Phalcon PresenceOf field is required

Tags: php, mysql, orm, phalcon

I have a problem with update records in database.
Here are errors:

```
Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Message Object
(
    [_type:protected] => PresenceOf
    [_message:protected] => field1 is required
    [_field:protected] => private
    [_model:protected] => 
    [_code:protected] => 0
)
Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Message Object
(
    [_type:protected] => PresenceOf
    [_message:protected] => field2 is required
    [_field:protected] => online
    [_model:protected] => 
    [_code:protected] => 0
)
```

This is the database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `data`
(
    `id`          BINARY(16)   NOT NULL,
    `id_second`   BINARY(16)   NOT NULL,
    `field1`      TINYINT(1)   NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `field2`      TINYINT(1)   NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `field3`      INTEGER      NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `name`        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `id_second`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_second`) REFERENCES `data2` (`id`)
);
```

I can create new record, but I can't update it.
After record find I'm trying to replace values and change it:

```
$record->name    = $save['name'];
$record->field1  = $save['field1'];
$record->field2  = $save['field2'];

$record->update();
```

But this displays errors given above. I don't know why, becouse when I display `$record->field1` and `$record->field2` they are not null but true or false (that's why it's `TINYINT` in database).

There are no validation rules in model and id and id_second fields are setted propertly.

I was trying to do this in this way:

```
    $result = Di::getDefault()->getModelsManager()->executeQuery('
        UPDATE \Pulsar\Model\Data SET
            name = :name:,
            field1 = :field1:,
            field2 = :field2:
        WHERE
            id = :id: AND id_second = :id_d2:
        ', [
            'id'     => $this->id,
            'id_d2'  => $this->id_second,
            'name'   => $this->name,
            'field1' => $this->field1,
            'field2' => $this->field2
        ], [
            'id'     => \PDO::PARAM_STR,
            'id_d2'  => \PDO::PARAM_STR,
            'name'   => \PDO::PARAM_STR,
            'field1' => \PDO::PARAM_INT,
            'field2' => \PDO::PARAM_INT
        ]
    );
```

But result is the same.
However, this works:

```
$v1 = $record->field1 ? 1 : 0;
$v2 = $record->field2 ? 1 : 0;
$record->getReadConnection()->execute("
    UPDATE data SET
        name = '{$record->name}',
        field1 = {$v1},
        field2 = {$v2}
    WHERE
        id = '{$record->id}' AND id_second = '{$record->id_second}'
");
```

How can I achieve the same with `update()` or `save()` function? I remind that `create()` and `delete()` functions are working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... I see why it's not working.
I'm posting `true` / `false` values, but it requires integer values.

So, passing `0` / `1` instead of `true` / `false` works correctly.